# How does elasticsearch facet feature work with async search query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am aware of how using the facet feature of elasticsearch, we can get the aggregated value of values for a specified field/s based on search query result data.

I have an application where I am monitoring logs and using elasticsearch to search through the log entries. On UI front I have a paging mechanism in place and hence using async feature of the search to fetch 'n' entries at a time.

So my question is, if I modify my async search query to fetch the facet information for certain fields, will it give the aggregated value for the sub-set of result that is fetched as a result of an async query. or will it get the aggregated value for the entire search result (and not the sub-set which is returned to user).

Many thanks and regards,
Komal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facets are returned for the entire search result. You can even set size to 0 in your request, which will result in not fetching any results and you will still get all facets.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) for detail documentation. You can give match all query to fetch facet on all documents `{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}`
Please post your code gist for more information.